# How to fix Druid Connectivity Error with Superset?

Tags: python, database, database-connection, apache-superset, druid

I am getting following error while configuring connection with Druid from Superset :

```
An error occurred while fetching databases:
{"_schema":[
"Engine spec \"DruidEngineSpec\" does not support being configured via individual parameters."
]}
```

Connection string being used is:

```
druid://admin:password1@192.168.4.171:8888/druid/v2/sql
```

PyDruid is already installed on Superset VM.

Comment: This was a bug in master, it should be fix by now. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Bug in master, where ? Superset or Druid ?

Comment: Bug in superset master :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error but with Oracle database, as Beto Dealmeida mentioned, seems to be a bug.

To **fix** this you should **create a new database and change your dashboards accordingly**.